# How to update a DataGridView that is populated with two database table

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is popoulated with the code below; Please note that the codes only contain the important part for brevity. The gridview populates well but the update code is what i need help on.

```
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Try
    'open database
    conn.Open()

    'get query data
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(
      "SELECT student_name.matric_no,student_name.sname, student_name.fname," &
      "result_sheet.course_title,result_sheet.test_score,result_sheet.exam_score,result_sheet.total_score" &
      " FROM student_name INNER JOIN result_sheet ON student_name.matric_no = result_sheet.matric_no  ", conn)

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

    ds = New DataSet()

    da.Fill(ds)
    da.Dispose()

    Dim usertable As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)

    'datasource of the datagrid
    Dview1.DataSource = usertable

    'change the data grid column name
    Dview1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "MATRIC NUMBER"
    Dview1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "SURNAME"
    Dview1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "FIRST NAME"

    conn.Close()
  Catch ex As Exception
    'display message
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)

  End Try
End Sub
```

My code to update the GridView is below;

```
Private Sub update_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                             ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles update_btn.Click
  Try
    da.Update(ds.Tables(0))
  Catch ex As Exception
    'display message
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
  End Try
End Sub
```

The error I am getting when I click on the Update button is: `The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized.`

Please, how do I solve this?

Comment: You need to specify which methods your 2 code pieces are part of, even better to include a class, to let us know if they are part of the same or different classes. Then it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: I have done that, please

Comment: some solutions are described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/10/15/editing-data-from-two-tables-in-a-single-datagridview.aspx

Comment: It looks like you did everything right. Ok, try this, remove all lines after `da.Fill(ds)`, i.e. you would fill and update, resulting in no change on the DB. Are you still getting an exception in this scenario? Also remove all Try/Catch blocks, they are not helping.

Comment: you dispose your DataAdapter (da) after you filled the dataset with it ... so you can't use it in update_btn_Click() without a new instantiation ...

Comment: Thanks, finally get it to work. THANKS...